# Looping through PHP array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

The question I want to ask is just out of my curiosity. Why doesn't this code work:

```
$table = [
    'key1'  => 'value1',
    'key2'  => 'value2',
];

foreach($table as $tb)
{
    $tb = strtoupper($tb);
}

print_r($table);
```

Comment: What do you expect? A bug is a discrepancy between your expectation and the actual result. The code works as long you do not expect anything.

Comment: wow, my mistake, it IS foreach($table as $tb) in the code, just copy-paste issue.

Comment: Isnt it obvious You have not defined $tbl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are expecting the values to become upper case..In that case you need `&` in foreach..

```
$table = [
    'key1'  => 'value1',
    'key2'  => 'value2',
];

foreach($table as &$tb)
{
    $tb = strtoupper($tb);
}

print_r($table);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. But why is that so? What is happening in the code I posted? It surely changes array values in the loop. Is it deleting them when the loop is closed?

Comment: the `&` means you're referencing a variable, so the actions done on such a variable will reflect back on the original

Comment: well said @Koen...thnx..

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand...so my code was creating some other variable $tb which was not the original variable?

Comment: what your code was doing was : it created an array, which is pointing to some memory location..now you are looping through the array, storing each member in a temporary location, any changes to that temp variable will ofcourse not reflect in orginal variable..Now with `reference` variables you are specifying it to update orignal value as well..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map`

```
$table = [
    'key1'  => 'value1',
    'key2'  => 'value2',
];

$table = array_map("strtoupper", $table);
print_r($table);
```

If you also what to change the keys to Upper case use `array_change_key_case`

```
 print_r(array_change_key_case($table, CASE_UPPER));
```